# Google Chrome extensions : setAttribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to open a link in a new tab in Google search. I check this code in the console and it worked :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elmements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

but in Google extensions, it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: If the attribute is accessible through the element itself don't do like `elements[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');` but do it like `elements[i].target = '_blank';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
elements[i].target = "_blank";
```